# How to replace your rails local pg db with the database in production on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have a db locally in my Rails app. The app is alreqady linked to Heroku through git. I want to totally replace my development db with the one in production on Heroku . How do it ? Are there a set of commands I can use locally to do the job for me ?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it with help of `heroku pg:backups:restore` command. see the detail document [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export). If you do not have any s2 url for dump install ngrok and put your file in public folder and provide that ngrok url of dump. This will help.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Heroku command for that:
`heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi`,
 where you replace each of those arguments with your app's information.
 (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql)

You could write a short rake task to fully replace your local db with Heroku using that command:

**lib/tasks/db.rake**

```
desc 'replaces local database with Heroku production database'
task replace_local_with_production: :environment do
  Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
  system heroku pg:pull HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAGENTA mylocaldb --app sushi
  Rake::Task['db:migrate'].invoke
end
```